# cURL and permanent login

Tags: php, session, curl

I'm using cURL to login on a website but the problem is, all login actions are registered on the server and it is impossible to login each time I want to perform a certain action.

I tried to do it this way:

1. $curl = curl_init();
2. some curl_setopts();
3. $_SESSION["curl"] = $curl;

so I could use it if needed on another moduels of my site (for different purposes but each of them require me to be logged in). It does not work. curl_exec won't work with $_SESSION["curl"] ("supplied argument is not a valid cURL handle resource").

How to handle that?

For every action I need to be logged but I don't want to login with cURL to perform different action separately.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you tried setting curl options `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to some file on server? Setting these would tell curl to read and store cookies there so the session would not be lost between requests.

Comment: Yup, I use these cURL options. So I just need to double them in other files and cURL will read them automatically?

Comment: They are for storing cookies. So if you log in once you should get your session cookie from server. Curl will automatically store and read it from file specified by those options. So next time (5 minutes later for example) you send request to server again and you should be logged in because you already have cookie with valid session ID.

Comment: It doesn't work. I use

    curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/www/cookies/cookies.txt' );
       curl_setopt (     $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/www/cookies/cookies.txt' );

in login.php and newpost.php and it works with login.php - no errors, but in newpost.php it says "Sorry, you need to be logged in", so cookies are not read properly.

Comment: Check permissions to directory inside which you want to store cookies. Must be `rwx` for user that owns apache process.

Comment: piotrek, permissions are fine, the cookies are stored

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to store variable `$curl` to `$_SESSION` because `curl_init` return type `resource`. From docs [Session - Introduction](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php).

```
Because session data is serialized, resource variables cannot be stored in the session.
```

Comment: I figured it out. It doesn't help at all, you know.